# index action is displaying show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

My controller

```
class AppController < ApplicationController

def index
  @users = User.all
end

def show
end
...
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>

<h1><%= user.name %><h1>
<%= user.age %>
<%end%>
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1>App#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/app/show.html.erb</p>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :app
....
```

But when I give the path to index
http://localhost:3000/app/index

instead of displaying index view it is displaying the content of show.html.erb.
What is the mistake I am doing , I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried just going to http://localhost:3000/app ? If you do `bin/rake routes ` in your terminal, you will see that the path for index is /app. Show will have /app/[:id] and it thinks you are passing index as the id, therefore it is using the show route

Comment: @aaron.v: You are right :) fixed the issue

Comment: controller and resources in routes.rb should be plural and models should be singular :)

Comment: @VishnuAtrai: rails itself created those names. I just gave controller App, and it created those.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that helped you. If you want to see more about how routes work, I would visit this [page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: @InQusitive while running generator we will have to take care, for controller generator provide plural name and for model generator provide singular name

Answer (score 0):

Not positive this is causing your problem, but shouldn't your controller be named

```
class AppsController < ApplicationController
```

instead of

```
class AppController < ApplicationController
```

and your views would be in `views/apps` not `views/app`